# Parallelizable nearly-Kahler manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202956/a-conjecture-about-parallelizable-generalized-spheres), we have discussed how the following bundle:

$E_{d} = TS^{d}\oplus \Lambda^2 T^{\ast}S^{d}$

is always trivial, where $S^{d}$ is the $d$-dimensional standard sphere. Now, let us take $d=6$. The six-sphere $S^{6}$ is an example of a strict nearly-Kahler homogeneous manifold which indeed is not parallelizable, although as we have said $E_{6}$ is. The natural question then is:

Is the vector bundle $W = TM_{6}\oplus \Lambda^{2} T^{\ast}M_{6}$ trivial, where $M_{6}$ is any homogeneous strict, nearly-Kahler manifold?

Notice that there are only four strict nearly-Kahler homogeneous manifolds, namely:

$S^{6},\qquad Sp(2)/(SU(2)\times U(1)), \qquad SU(3)/(U(1)\times U(1)), \qquad S^{3}\times S^{3}.$

For $S^{6}$ we already know that the answer is affirmative, and in fact, since $S^{3}$ is parallelizable, then the $W$ corresponding to $S^{3}\times S^{3}$ is also trivial. So there are only two cases left to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 'no'.  Already, it is not true for $M = \mathrm{Sp}(2)/\bigl(\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{U}(1)\bigr)$, which is known to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^3$.

To see this, note that the first Pontrjagin class of $T\mathbb{CP}^3$ satisfies
$$
p_1(T\mathbb{CP}^3) = 8u^2\in H^4(\mathbb{CP}^3,\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $u\in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^3,\mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{R}$ is the standard generator.  By the usual formula, this implies that
$$
p_1\bigl(\Lambda^2(T\mathbb{CP}^3)\bigr) = 32u^2,
$$
so that
$$
p_1\bigl(T\mathbb{CP}^3\oplus\Lambda^2(T\mathbb{CP}^3)\bigr) = 40 u^2\not=0.
$$
In particular, $T\mathbb{CP}^3\oplus\Lambda^2(T\mathbb{CP}^3)$ is not a trivial bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^3$.

Comment: @Bilateral:  Well, I don't have any new idea for this, just the one I used above, adapted to this case:  Try to find a nearly parallel $\mathrm{G}_2$-manifold $M^7$ such that $p_1(TM)$ is nonzero in $H^4(M,\mathbb{R})$.  Since one would then have $p_1\bigl(TM \oplus \Lambda^2(TM)\bigr) = 6 p_1(TM)\not=0$, this would answer your question in the negative.  Have you gone through the known homogeneous examples to check this condition (which can, of course, be done purely algebraically)?  Note that $M = \mathrm{SO}(5)/\mathrm{SO}(3)$ won't work because $H^4(M,\mathbb{R}) = (0)$ in this case.

Comment: @Bilateral:  I am not sure that I understand your comment. Are you saying that you have checked that all of the homogeneous nearly parallel $\mathrm{G}_2$-manifolds have vanishing $p_1$?

Comment: @Bilateral:  So, really, the question you should be asking is how to find examples of nearly parallel $\mathrm{G}_2$-structures for which the bundle $W$ is trivial, not for a proof that this is always so.